# Converting Seconds into days, hours, minutes, and seconds

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to Python and am having trouble with this problem. I want to create a program where a user inputs a number of seconds, and it converts it to days, hours, minutes and seconds. However, for example, I want the program for 100,000 seconds to output 1 day, 3 hours, 46 minutes, 40 seconds. However, mine also inputs the calculations with decimals, like it will say 1.157 days and the same for the rest of the categories. Any help will be appreciated, thank you so much.

```
def SecondsConvertor(x):
    d = x/86400
    h = (x%86400)/3600
    m = (x%3600)/60
    s = (x%60)
    print("Your input is equal to", d, "days,", h, "hours,", m, "minutes,", "and", s, "seconds.")
x = 100000

SecondsConvertor(x)
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow!  The problem is how you're handling your math, and how you still use the total seconds even after they've been taken by larger units.  For example with this setup, the input 86,400 would return 1 day, 24 hours, 60 minutes, and 86400 seconds.  But, I'll help you with a fix!

Comment: Oh I see, yeah how would there be a way to fix? I just learned the % and tried using that.

Comment: Yep, just posted a whole script!  And it works, I pretested for ya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting every variable to integer should erase decimals as you want, so use it like `d = int(x/86400)` for all of your variables (d, h, m and s).

Comment: Hey, Thanks so much, now I know integer doesn't have decimals.

Comment: The main problem with this is that the math will be incredibly wrong if the value of x isn't changed.  But as long as he keeps using the % before the division, it'll work

Answer (score 0):

```
def SecondConverter(x):
    d = int(x/86400)  #The int call removes the decimals.  Conveniently, it always rounds down.  int(2.9) returns 2 instead of 3, for example.
    x-=(d*86400)  #This updates the value of x to show that the already counted seconds won't be double counted or anything.
    h = int(x/3600)
    x-=(h*3600)
    m = int(x/60)
    x -= (m*60)
    s = x
    print("Your input is equal to ", d, " days, ", h, " hours, ", m, " minutes, and ", s, "seconds.")

SecondConverter(100000)

#gives 1 day, 3 hours, 46 minutes, and 40 seconds.
```

Comment: Thanks for being so kind man. I can see why this is such a great community :).

Comment: Happy to help!  And yeah, welcome to the SO community!  Actually just about to edit my answer to point out what's different.